# Implementing toUpper function in MIPS

Tags: assembly, converters, mips, toupper

So I'm trying to implement a kind of toUpper function in MIPS. The function has access to two variables: $a0, which is the starting address of a string of characters, and $a1 which is the length of the string. I'm trying to loop through the string and convert it to uppercase. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

I think I'm having trouble actually loading the first character from the starting address into a variable.

```
to_upper:

    li $t0, 0 #initialize counter  
    li $t1, 0

Loop: 
    addi $t0, $t0, 1

    sgt $t5, $t0, $a1   
    beqi $t5, 1, Done   

    slti $t5, $t1, 97
    beqi $t5, 1, Loop

    sgti $t5,$t1, 122
    beqi $t5, 1, Loop

    subi $t1, $t1, 32

j Loop

    Done:
    jr $ra
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to place

```
addi $t0, $t0, 1
```

at the end of the loop.

So, like this:

```
...
Loop:
    addi $t5, $a0, $t0
    lb $t6, 0($t5)
    ...set $t6 to upper...
    sb $t6, 0($t5)
    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    blt $t0, $a1, Loop
Done:
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`$a0` is not referenced anywhere in this code.  You need to load values from `$a0` using `lb`, modify them, and then store them back.

Comment: You need to load bytes with lb. lw will not work as expected.